# How can I detect the presence of a class and add or remove another class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js theme-light"> or
<html lang="en" class="no-js xxx yyy theme-light">
```

I would like to make it so that clicking a link will change this to:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js theme-dark"> 
<html lang="en" class="no-js xxx yyy theme-dark">
```

Clicking again will change it back. that is remove `theme-dark` and add `theme-light`.

Can someone explain how I can do this with `jQuery`?

```
 $('#sidebar-theme-switch').click(function (e) {
    ???
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#sidebar-theme-switch').click(function() {
    $('html').toggleClass('theme-light theme-dark')
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXNV3/)

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.